# How to get AWS access key and secret key using aws-sdk-ruby --aws-sdk-iam,aws-sdk-core

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, automated-tests, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm a newbie to aws and ruby. I'm trying to get access key and the secret key using the aws-sdk-ruby, as due to security reasons we do not have access to keys in the AWS Console. I tried to use the 'get_federation_token' 'assume role with SAML' to get the keys, but I was not successful. I tried both the ways as we use the saml2aws and aws-federator to login to the AWS via the CLI. I would want to replicate that and get the keys to able to connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up ENV vars in a .env file and then fetching via `ENV.fetch('variable_name')`, like, `ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')`? This works consistently for me.